# Use xpath to check if a string has only ASCII characters

Tags: xpath, ascii, xquery

I'm trying to check if a string has only ASCII characters using this query `contains($ASCIISupportAddressSet/ns2:Label,'[ -~\n\t]')`. However I want this pseudo-code to work with xpath:

```
if (matches('АДЫГЕЙСК',[A-Z]) then
  task 1
else 
  task 2.
```

What is the correct xpath syntax for this, if it is possible at all?

Comment: Could you please show your xpath expression.

Comment: I'm trying to check if the label element content has any non ASCII characters. below is the code which I'm trying to use but it is not working. contains($ASCIISupportAddressSet/Label,'[ -~\n\t]')                                      
Label has below content.                                                                     
АДЫГЕЙСК
АДЫГЕЙСК
АДЫГЕЯ РЕСПУБЛИКА

Comment: As @MichaelKay points out, although XPath (and XML in general) uses the Unicode character set, its [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block happens to coincide with the characters in the ASCII character set. You can capitalize on that.

Answer (score 4):

As @MadsHansen says, but you could also write

```
not(matches($x, "\p{IsBasicLatin}"))
```

The `matches()` call here returns true if there is a non-basic-latin character in the string. The Unicode block `BasicLatin` matches x00 to x7F, that is effectively ASCII.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki the upper '\P' means negation and it is totally fine to use in xsl. And also the correct answer for this will be the first answer given by Michael.  See documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html.

Answer (score 2):

Testing whether the regex `[ -~\n\t]` matches ASCII characters will evaluate to true if there happens to be even one ASCII character, such as a space. The example value that you mentioned in your comment would pass.

A couple of solutions for testing whether the value has non-ASCII characters:

To ensure that the regex only matches if ALL characters are ASCII, ensure that the character class applies is anchored from start to end by adding `^` and `$` at the beginning and end of the regex, and add `+` to require one to many ASCII character in between:

```
if ( fn:matches($ASCIISupportAddressSet/ns2:Label,'^[ -~\n\t]+$') ) ) then
  (: has ASCII characters - task 1 :)
else
  (: has non-ASCII-only characters - task 2 :)
```

Or, if you negate your original regex, you can easily test for the presence of a non-ASCII character:

```
if ( fn:matches($ASCIISupportAddressSet/ns2:Label,'[^ -~\n\t]') ) then
  (: has non-ASCII characters - task 2 :)
else
  (: has ASCII-only characters - task 1 :)
```

And then you can negate that with [`fn:not()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-not), and still keep the if/else invoking task 1 if the value only has ASCII characters:

```
if ( fn:not( fn:matches($ASCIISupportAddressSet/ns2:Label,'[^ -~\n\t]') ) ) then
  (: has ASCII characters - task 1 :)
else
  (: has non-ASCII-only characters - task 2 :)
```